# How to execute a stored procedure in EF Core 5 in .NET 5 Web API?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5, ef-core-5.0

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which I am trying to execute with code as attached in the screenshot shown below. This stored procedure is returning some raw json, not any object or entity.

I found on Google that we can do it using the `FromSqlRaw` function, but I am not getting that function at all in Intellisense. Can someone please tell me how I can execute it using EF Core 5 in .NET 5? I just want to execute it and store its result in a variable.

This is my code:

[image]

Comment: Please check this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/tree/main/samples/core/Querying/RawSQL) from official EFcore repo

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) will help you.